# Assign started application to a specific task bar icon

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

At work we use a lot of browser based applications (SharePoint, Jira and many others). Some of those require a special browser to be used (e.g. SharePoint currently only works in InternetExplorer, Jira only in Chrome).

=> The whole situation (three different browsers, lots of bookmarks) is quite unsatisfactory :-)

So I decided to create a tool that wraps web links into executables:

- Each "launcher" opens a specific link
- Each launcher knows which browser to use
- Each launcher has a nice icon to identify the web application it opens
- The launchers can be added to the start menu easily

Now only one thing isn't as it should be: When such a launcher opens a specific browser, the browser will (obviously) appear as a new icon on the task bar. Is there any way how I could "group" the started browser application under the launcher's icon in the task bar?

Answer (score 0):

(WINDOWS 10)

Search Taskbar settings on start menu.

Go to the Combine taskbar icons dropdown list and select "Always Combine, remove Labels"

Comment: But how should Windows know that my launcher application and the browser it started belong together?

Comment: @Boris you can either hide ur application icon or you can manipulate the taskbar icons of the browsers . or you can hide the browser icons and only activate them when you press your application icon.